# Select row if column value can be found in a string

Tags: sqlite

I have a string that contains ID numbers, something like this: „1;3;5;6;7;“

I want to select all rows in an SQLite table that have an ID which is contained in that string.

One select statement that gives me the rows 1,3,5,6 and 7.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [`LIKE`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/) operator:

```
select * from tablename
where ';' || '1;3;5;6;7' || ';' like '%;' || id || ';%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQLite [instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) core function

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE instr(';'||'1;3;5;6;7;',';'||id||';');
```

- preceding the list with ; and wrapping the id in ;'s ensures that only the specific values are extracted (e.g. so that 1 doesn't get 11 111 etc)